# Angular.js dynamic time filter

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I have MySQL table called events:

```
id|  descr  |  time_from |  time_to |
1 | wake up |  10:00:00  | 10:15:00 |
2 |   play  |  11:00:00  | 12:00:00 |
3 |   walk  |  14:00:00  | 14:30:00 |
```

I loop throught this table using ng-repeat and I've try to apply own filter, that should filter events by current time. So as you can guess, with this filter only one event should be displayed. Below you can see, what I have tried to do.

This is how I select events and prepare json for angular:

```
<?
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db('organaizer');
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events');
    while($lesson = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $rows[] = $lesson;
        }
    print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Events shows up well with no errors.
Angular code:

```
function eventsCtrl($scope, $http)
    {
        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'events.php'}).success(function(data)
            {
                $scope.events = data; // response data 
            });
        $scope.currentTime = function(lesson)
            {
                //Filter by current time
            }
    }
```

The markup:

```
<div class='well' style='margin:10px;' ng-app ng-controller="eventsCtrl">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Start at</th>
        <th>End at</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:currentTime">
        <td>{{event.id}}</td>
        <td>{{event.descr}}</td>
        <td>{{event.time_from}}</td>
        <td>{{event.time_to}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So, I've tried to apply filter using the example of [$interval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) on angularjs.org using time format `"HH:mm:ss"`, but unfortunately this doesn't help.
Maybe you have better ideas how to do this.

Comment: Does anything show up? Are there any errors? What is the data type of `time_from` and `time_to` (Strings, Dates,...)? Are you sure your `currentTime` function gets called?

Comment: Nothing show up, no errors. Data type for `time_from` and `time_to` is string. And I'm completly sure, that `currentTime` being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the "my-current-time" directive in the example you've mentioned [$interval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval).

I'm pretty sure that there might be a better solution, but this works.

Please refer to the comments inside the code

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="Ang" ng-cloak>
    <div class='well' style='margin:10px;' ng-controller="eventsCtrl">
        <input type="text" my-current-time="format">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Start at</th>
                    <th>End at</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:currentTime"> <!-- here we're filtering using time_from as 10:00:00 -->
                    <td>{{event.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{event.descr}}</td>
                    <td>{{event.time_from}}</td>
                    <td>{{event.time_to}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('Ang', [])
        .controller('eventsCtrl', eventsCtrl)
        .directive('myCurrentTime', function($interval, dateFilter) {
            // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var format,  // date format
                    stopTime; // so that we can cancel the time updates

                // used to update the UI
                function updateTime() {
                    element.val(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
                    scope.time = element.val();
                }

                // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
                scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
                    format = value;
                    updateTime();
                });

                stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

                // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
                // to prevent updating time ofter the DOM element was removed.
                element.bind('$destroy', function() {
                    $interval.cancel(stopTime);
                });
            }
        });

function eventsCtrl($scope, $http, dateFilter)
{
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'events.php'}).success(
        function(data)
        {
            $scope.events = data; // response data
        }
    );
    $scope.currentTime = function(lesson)
    {
        return ($scope.time >= lesson.time_from && $scope.time <= lesson.time_to)
    };

    $scope.format = 'h:mm:ss';
    $scope.time = dateFilter(new Date(), $scope.format);

}
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db('organaizer');
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events');

    while($lesson = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) // Using mysql_fetch_object() function here is better when trying to convert it to JSON ( without adding extra key:value pairs to the data as in mysql_fetch_array() function)
    {
        $rows[] = $lesson;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Hope this could help

Comment: By the way I used 'GET' method to retrieve the data in $http call from javascript, but 'POST' would work fine. It's just convenient for me to use 'GET' since we are actually getting data and not posting any in this case.

Comment: Hello @LiGhT MaN, welcome to Stack Overflow.  When providing an answer, it's considered good form to explain the "why" for your answer and not just the "what" or "how".  For example, you could improve this answer and help out future readers by explaining the key piece of the solution contained in your code.

Comment: @DavidPope thanks for the heads up, I've update the answer and hope it's more clear now. My bad, that's my first post here

Comment: I think you don't understand my question.
All events from MySQL table shows up.
And there is no difference between `<?` and `<?php`.
I remind that my question was "how apply filter with dynamic time"

Comment: @john_cave17 Probably I misunderstood your question, could you elaborate more about "dynamic time"

Comment: Of course.
We have a `clock` variable in JS that equal to current time:
`var clock = new Date()`.
Than we updating value of current time using `setInterval()`.
After this we get values of current hours,minutes and seconds using `.getHours`, `.getMinutes` and `.getSeconds`.
I want to filter events where `currentTime>=time_from and currentTime<time_to`.
That's all

Comment: @john_cave17 Alright, I think I've fixed the code as you would want it to be. Please check it again as I've updated it and hope this time I got it right.

Comment: Well, i'm also fixed my own code almost the same way, but it still don't work. You can check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7A7knFQZd0NIcf26reO?p=preview)

Comment: @LiGhTMaN anyway your code work well. Can you fix my version of code at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7A7knFQZd0NIcf26reO?p=preview) ?

Comment: @john_cave17 your code works fine, it's just the condition in "ownFilter" should be the opposite like so (event.time_from<=$scope.time && event.time_to>=$scope.time)